# XML and XSLT-V2 processing or unnest deeply nested lists in R - data from the Pharmaceutical Benefits Scheme

Tags: r, xml, xslt-2.0, nested-lists, xslt-3.0

### Question:

My colleges and I have been trying to convert the Pharmaceutical Benefits Scheme V3 XML (https://www.pbs.gov.au/browse/downloads) into a usable format for a long time and we've had limited success. I've been able to convert the [PBS XML V3](http://www.pbs.gov.au/downloads/2020/09/2020-09-01-xml-V3.zip) into an R list of lists however unpacking that into a usable format programmatically has been very difficult.

```
PBS_V3_XML_Doc <- read_xml(x = Path_to_PBS_V3_XML_File
              ,options = c("RECOVER", "NOBLANKS", "HUGE")   # Important options that enable import. 
                         # Lifts hardcoded limitations because of the massive file size 
               ,verbose = TRUE)    # Enables message print feedback


PBS_V3_XML_NameSpaces <- xml_ns(PBS_V3_XML_Doc)           # xml namespaces 
PBS_V3_XML_List <- xml2::as_list(x = PBS_V3_XML_Doc)    # converts the XML document into a R list object
```

I've tried combinations of unnest_wider, unnest_longer, unnest, unlist, unnest_auto, and many more (some below). But we havent had any luck.

```
Test_docall_unnest <- do.call(c, unlist(PBS_V3_XML_List, recursive=FALSE))

flattenlist <- function(x){  
        morelists <- sapply(x, function(xprime) class(xprime)[1]=="list")
        out <- c(x[!morelists], unlist(x[morelists], recursive=FALSE))
        if(sum(morelists)){ 
                Recall(out)
                }else{
        return(out) }}

recursive_unnest <- function(.data) {
        # Exit condition: no more 'children' list-column
        if (!"children" %in% names(.data) || !is.list(.data[["children"]])) return(.data)
        x <- unnest(.data)
        # Minor clean-up to make unnest work: replace NULLs with empty data frames
        x <- mutate_if(x, is.list, 
                ~ map_if(.x, ~ is.null(.x) || identical(.x, list()), ~ data.frame(date = NA)))           Recall(x)  
}
```

#### Part of the solution

Using stylesheets may have worked however the xslt package doesnt accept XML stylesheets that are version 2 or higher, so sadly that package doesnt help out for this situation.
I've tried using a few of the xsl stylesheets found within the [PBS V3 Schema found here](https://dev.pbs.gov.au/content/schema/current/pbs-current.zip), but I'm honestly unsure which stylesheet I should be using (I have tried the file within the /xsl folder)
[image: Errors shown on attempting to apply a xsl to the xml]
[image: R Termination]

Answer (score 0):

Why not XSLT 1.0 script which R's `xslt` package can run? XSLT 1.0 script can flatten needed nodes and all their descendants limited to nodes with text information. The repeated node appears to be the `<previous>` tags. Once flattened, transformed XML can migrate easily into data frame. Each descendant has its parent and grandparent names attached to return name to be complete for data frame columns.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:pbs="http://schema.pbs.gov.au/"
                              xmlns:p="http://pbs.gov.au/"
                              xmlns:dbk="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
                              xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook#"
                              xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                              xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
                              xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                              xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
                              xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
                              xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                              xmlns:ext="http://extension.schema.pbs.gov.au/"
                              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="pbs:root">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="pbs:previous-list"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="pbs:previous-list">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="pbs:previous"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="pbs:previous">
     <data>
       <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*">
           <xsl:if test="text() != ''">
           <xsl:element name="{translate(concat(local-name(../parent::*), '_', local-name(parent::*), '_', local-name()), '-', '_')}">
               <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
           </xsl:element>
           </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </data>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**XSLT Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B72)</kbd>

**R**

```
library(xml2)
library(xslt)
library(dplyr)

# INPUT SOURCE
doc <- read_xml("/path/to/sch-2020-09-01-r1.xml")
style <- read_xml("/path/to/style.xsl", package = "xslt")

# TRANSFORM 
new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)

# RETRIEVE data NODES
recs <- xml_find_all(new_xml, "//data")

# BIND EACH CHILD TEXT AND NAME TO Player DFs
df_list <- lapply(recs, function(r) 
  data.frame(rbind(setNames(xml_text(xml_children(r)), 
                            xml_name(xml_children(r)))),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)

# BIND ALL DFs TO SINGLE MASTER DF
final_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(df_list)
```

Comment: Hi there @Parfait, 
As far as I know, xslt doesnt support xsl stylesheets version 2 or greater. I think, _think_ that the stylesheet for the PBS is pbs-3.1.9-308/xsl/check-ontology.xsl or pbs-3.1.9-308/schematron/validator.xsl but I'm actually unsure. Either way, when I tried the new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style) method R Crashed and terminated every single time. I believed it was because xslt only referenced a libary that supported xslt Version 1, not xslt version 2. Is that correct or is it something else? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Please note I do not use any of PBS's stylesheets but one created here. I tested this solution with downloaded file. XSLT does have versions including [1.0, 2.0, and even 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) (identified in root of script) where the processor used must adhere to declared version. R's `xslt` package can run 1.0 scripts. PBS may use a different version. But 1.0 is adequate enough as demo shows to flatten nodes for dataframe import. Please use this posted XSLT for `/path/to/style.xsl`.

Comment: I thought you created that stylesheet, great to know. It may be viable strategy to create a stylesheet ourselves and work from there - great example, thank you. 
My references to XSLT versions are about the Rpackage xslt, not the XSLT language itself. Sorry about the ambiguity. In the [Rpackage xslt documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/xslt/man/xslt.html) it reads "..supports XSLT 1.0 features plus most of the EXSLT set of processor-portable extensions functions. Unfortunately XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 features are only available in proprietary libraries and currently unsupported...."

Comment: Understood. For future readers, does this XSLT and R solution help import the XML file into a data frame in usable format for your needs?

Comment: Regarding R's `xslt` package, under the hood it calls [`libxslt` C library](https://github.com/cran/xslt/blob/master/src/xslt.cpp). But you are not limited to this. You can have R call externally installed 2.0 and 3.0 processors like Saxon (some of which have free versoins) at command line with `system()`. Sadly, the web industry did not upgrade and still uses the 1999 1.0 standard of over 20 years! But most XSLT developers do run 2.0+.

Comment: For future readers, for this situation with importing the PBS XML V3 with XSLT and R, it hasnt worked yet and I dont think it will. It may work using xml2 with converting the xml to a list and unnesting it or using xpaths, but I dont see those working in an automated process. Yeah, I've been trying to run Saxon and some of the alternatives, but I keep runing into trouble either reading in the xml (file is too large) or needing to compile Java which is way outside my expertise (I've tried several times).

Comment: I am confused. I tested my above XSLT on a downloaded PBS XML V3 (at your posted link) on a Ubuntu laptop with 8 GB RAM and had no issues importing and transforming that single XML (6 MB file). Can you confirm you used my XSLT (not a different one) on XML at link download (not a different one)?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response. I believe that your reccommendation to create our own XSLT will probably work, but I'd have to learn how to write the entire transformation. I could do this but the PBS regularly updates the XML with additional attributes which makes it harder to automate. I hoped that a xslt transform file would come with the PBS zip for each release, but I cant find one that runs well within R. To my knowledge the XLST file you gave in your example didnt transform the entire XML, unless I am incorrect in that statement?

Comment: This is the [link](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B72) referenced in the last comment. That is the correct xslt site you're referring to, correct? Using that same program, I couldn't upload the PBS XML file and start creating an XSLT myself. Open to recommendations and suggestions though. Greatly appreciate the help @Parfait

Comment: XSLT in this solution retrieves *every* descendant of `<pbs:previous>` node. It can be changed to any node.

Comment: Upon re-reading this thread with some reflection, @Parfait I think you may be right. Is there any chance you can please share which 2.0 or 3.0 processor (Saxon or other) you use and the `system()` command used to get this working? Actually, was a 2.0/3.0 processor required with the example xsl you provided earlier?

Comment: As mentioned, I used XSLT 1.0 in this solution, the version supported in `xslt` package.